# Creating a table from JSON response in Flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, datatable

I am trying to make a data table in Flutter that is very dynamical, in the sense that it changes completely with every response. Is there any packages or widgets to make a data table from a JSON response like this:

```
{"array":[["mr", "500", "140,00", "7,00", "147,00"], ["vrijednost", "140.00", "Kn"], ["jm ko\u010dna Glena", "", "KOM 20000. 7,00.", "Vrijednost bez PDV-a", "Iznos PDV-a :", "UKUPNO SA PDV-om"], ["poreza", "7,00"], ["naziv artikla-usluge", "", "BIJELI KRUH 600 gr", "", "osnovica iznos", "140.00"], ["\u017eovratni", "\u0161ifra artikla", "more", "%", "5,00"]]}
```

Thank You very much for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to "massage" your data once you have it in `Map<String, dynamic>` format, determining which are the headers (columns) of the table and which the data groups (cells/rows).

To generate these dynamically have a look at [`DataTable`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html).

```dart
DataTable(
  columns: getColumnArray(), // returns DataColumns with Text for headers
  rows: getRowArray(), // returns DataRows & DataCells with Texts for grouped data
)
```